# How to decorate the ValidationError in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm using Django form to control the length of content.The function works,but the errors information contains some extra words and punctuation marks that I don't need.

My question is how to delete the extra words and punctuation marks?

Here is my form:

```
def words_validator(comment):
    if len(comment) < 4:
        raise ValidationError("您输入的评论字数太短，请重新输入至少4个字符")

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), validators=[words_validator])
```

Here is my template:

```
      {% if comment_form.errors %}
         <div class="ui error" >
           {{comment_form.errors}}
         </div>
     {% endif %}
```

The errors message is here:

```
·comment
   。您输入的评论字数太短，请重新输入至少4个字符
```

I only need '**您输入的评论字数太短，请重新输入至少4个字符**',don't want the punctuation marks and the field name '**comment**'.

Any friend has a solution?

Comment: That's because `comment_form.errors` is the dictionary of all form errors. You should print field errors next to each field using `{{ comment_form.comment.errors }}` (for the `comment` field) and only non-field errors using `{{ comment_form.non_field_errors }}`.

Comment: Thank you so much!{{ comment_form.comment.errors }} works ,but still a '.' there,do you have any way can get rid of the '.'?

Comment: That’s because by default Django wraps errors in a <ul> putting each in a <li> element so you’ll see bullets. Just change your css for <ul> with class `errorlist` to not show bullets.

Comment: Man,you provide the best answer!Very simple!Thank you!

Comment: @dirkgroten man could you also help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014809/reverse-for-update-comment-with-arguments-not-found-1-patterns-trie?noredirect=1#comment87046628_50014809 it is too hard and nobody can solve it up to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over form, then field.errors,

Like,

```
{% for field in form %}
   {% for error in field.errors %}
       {{ error }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Example:

myapp.forms.py

```
def words_validator(comment):
    if len(comment) < 4:
        raise ValidationError("Lenght should be greater than 4")


class Demo(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), validators=[words_validator])
```

Shell:

```
In [1]: html = """
   ...: {% for field in form %}
   ...:     {% for error in field.errors %}
   ...:         {{ error }}
   ...:     {% endfor %}
   ...: {% endfor %}
   ...:
   ...: """

In [2]: from django.template import Context, Template

In [3]: from myapp.forms import *

In [4]: form = Demo({'comment': 'abc'})

In [5]: t = Template(html)

In [6]: c = Context({'form': form})

In [7]: print t.render(c)



        Lenght should be greater than 4
```